# WordPress plugins add parent menu option in admin bar

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I need to add a menu item but it is available as a parent item, I am trying it as follows but in the menu option it is shown as the child of the parent item Settings> My plugins name:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin' );

function my_plugin() {
    add_options_page( 
        'My Options',
        'My plugins name',
        'my_plugin',
        'my-plugin.php',
        'my_plugin_page'
    );
}
```

I have reviewed this section: https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities, but there are many options, I am learning to create plugins for WordPress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use following function:

```
add_menu_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability,
               $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
```

The detailed guide can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus

So in your case, your `my_plugin` function will look like this:

```
function my_plugin() {
    add_menu_page( 
        "My Plugin settings", 
        "My Plugin", 
        "manage_options", 
        "my-plugin-settings", 
        "my_plugin_settings_page", 
        "dashicons-admin-generic"
    );
}
```

Of course you will have to define the function `my_plugin_settings_page` which will render the actual testing page, for example:

```
function my_plugin_settings_page() {
    echo 'Hello, this is the my plugin setting page";
}
```